# How to parse a complicated JSON with Go unmarshal?

Tags: json, parsing, go

In `go` the standard package [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) exposes `json.Unmarshal` function to parse JSON.

It's possible to either unmarshal the JSON string in a predefined `struct`, or use the `interface{}` and iterate the result for unexpected JSON data structure.

That said, I can't parse complex JSON properly. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

```
 {
     "k1" : "v1", 
     "k2" : "v2", 
     "k3" : 10, 
     "result" : [
                 [
                 ["v4", v5, {"k11" : "v11", "k22" : "v22"}]
                 , ... , 
                 ["v4", v5, {"k33" : "v33", "k44" : "v44"}
                 ]
                 ], 
                 "v3"
                ] 
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Citing from [JSON and Go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go):

> Without knowing this data's structure, we can decode it into an interface{} value with Unmarshal:

```
b := []byte(`{
   "k1" : "v1", 
   "k3" : 10,
   result:["v4",12.3,{"k11" : "v11", "k22" : "v22"}]
}`)
var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
```

> At this point the Go value in f would be a map whose keys are strings and whose values are themselves stored as empty interface values:

```
f = map[string]interface{}{
    "k1": "v1",
    "k3":  10,
    "result": []interface{}{
       "v4",
       12.3,
       map[string]interface{}{
           "k11":"v11",
           "k22":"v22",
       },
    },
}
```

> To access this data we can use a type assertion to access `f`'s underlying map[string]interface{}:

```
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
```

> We can then iterate through the map with a range statement and use a type switch to access its values as their concrete types:

```
for k, v := range m {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
    case int:
        fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        for i, u := range vv {
            fmt.Println(i, u)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
    }
}
```

> In this way you can work with unknown JSON data while still enjoying the benefits of type safety.

More information about Go and JSON can be found in the original article. I  changed the code snippets slightly to be more similar to the JSON in the question.

Comment: var holder interface{}
 json.Unmarshal(message, &holder)
 return determineTypeHelper(holder.(map[string]interface{})) . iam doing this and getting the following error??? interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}

Comment: Just wanted to mention, `var f interface{}; err := yaml.Unmarshal(b, &f)` also works with `github.com/go-yaml/yaml`.

Comment: I also get the error "interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}". Any ideas?

Comment: interface{} is nil because the json string is not valid. results should be "results". Here is a playground with the above code example (using the json correction): https://play.golang.org/p/RLodJLwy19

Comment: @johan Seven years after you posted your answer, it really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

More recently, [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) offers selection of properties in JSON

```
k1 := gjson.Get(json, "k1")
k33 : = gjson.Get(json, "result.#.#.k33")
```

Comment: Didn't know about this one, thanks! I've updated my post, as I happen to learn more about this stuff recently, hope that may be useful to you too.

Answer (score 6):

### Using standard library `encoding/json` package

I've worked of [JSON and Go](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) article, and it turned out that `case int` doesn't work and it need to be `case float64` now, and there is plenty of nesting in real-world JSON.

```
> go version
go version go1.7.1 darwin/amd64
```

I've also looked at [JSON decoding in Go](http://attilaolah.eu/2013/11/29/json-decoding-in-go/), but it didn't help me very much as I needed to do proceduralrly traform it into a series of calls to mruby binding, and the author of that article is happy with Go structs for most part.

I've spent a little while fiddling with this and final iterating dumper function looked like this:

```
func dumpJSON(v interface{}, kn string) {
    iterMap := func(x map[string]interface{}, root string) {
        var knf string
        if root == "root" {
            knf = "%q:%q"
        } else {
            knf = "%s:%q"
        }
        for k, v := range x {
            dumpJSON(v, fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
        }
    }

    iterSlice := func(x []interface{}, root string) {
        var knf string
        if root == "root" {
            knf = "%q:[%d]"
        } else {
            knf = "%s:[%d]"
        }
        for k, v := range x {
            dumpJSON(v, fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
        }
    }

    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%s => (string) %q\n", kn, vv)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%s => (bool) %v\n", kn, vv)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%s => (float64) %f\n", kn, vv)
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%s => (map[string]interface{}) ...\n", kn)
        iterMap(vv, kn)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%s => ([]interface{}) ...\n", kn)
        iterSlice(vv, kn)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%s => (unknown?) ...\n", kn)
    }
}
```

With `b` being a byte slice with a JSON representing either an array or an object at the top-level, you can call it like this:

```
var f interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
dumpJSON(f, "root")
```

[*Hope this helps, you try the comple program here*](https://play.golang.org/p/WOMMJvUXUA).

### Using other packages

I would recommend not doing it yourself, unless you feel you have to learn how Go types work and using `reflect` makes you feel like a master of the universe (personally, `reflect` drives me mad).

As [@changingrainbows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044126/changingrainbows) [pointed out below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828598/717998), there is [`github.com/tidwall/gjson`](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) package, which appears to wrap `encoding/json` and uses `reflect`. I may be not dissimilar from `github.com/mitchellh/reflectwalk`, which is pretty hard to use and inner workings are rather very complicated.

I have used [`github.com/buger/jsonparser`](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser) rather extensively in one of my projects, and there is also [`github.com/json-iterator/go`](https://github.com/json-iterator/go), which I've not tried yet, but it appears to be based on `github.com/buger/jsonparser` and appears to expose `enconding/json`-compatible interface and has [`func Get(data []byte, path ...interface{}) Any`](https://godoc.org/github.com/json-iterator/go#Get) as well. For the record, Kubernetes project has recently switched to `github.com/json-iterator/go`.
In my project, I use `encoding/json` as well as `github.com/buger/jsonparser`, I'll probably switch to `github.com/json-iterator/go` when I have time. I will try to update this post with more findings.