# Golang yaml.v2 umarshalling complex nested structs

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

Assume such a yaml:

```
A:
  B0:
    synonym: XX
    C1:
    - value1
    - value2
  B2:
    synonym: ZZ
    C7:
    - value17
    C3:
    - value99
AX:
  B7:
    synonym: GG
    C99:
    - value123
```

In addition, assume that all the A, B and C names are arbitrary names, and that there might be many more B entries, each with a synonym and [0-n[ C entries.

How would a gopkg.in/yaml.v2 mapping look like with which I could parse such a yaml file?

The examples I found in the docs or in the web don't deal with more complex nested structures (or I didn't understand them right).

Comment: This seems to work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341588/how-to-parse-a-complicated-json-with-go-unmarshal